# UITableView Swipe Delete:delete button appears sometimes only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, edit

In my app,I was trying to implement swipe to delete function for TableView.I followed the following codes.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
      //code to delete
    }
}
```

> UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer 
{
     return YES;
}
```

But the issue is that  commitEditingStyle method gets called about 1/20 times only.What can be the issue??Thank you.PLease help.